# Compare nested if conditions and single if conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, nested-loops

I am working on the enhancement project. In many areas I have seen people using nested if conditions. According to me it is a bad idea as we can use the single If condition to do the same. Is there any specific reason to use nested condition. Which one the following code will be efficient to use ?

```
if (Condi1== True) {
 if (Condi2== True) {
  if (Condi3== True) {
   int answer = True;
  }
 }
}
```

OR

```
if((Condi1== True)&&(Condi2== True)&&(Condi3== True))
{
   int answer = True;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to me it is a bad idea as we can use the single If condition to do the same.

Before you go too far down that path I suggest you compare the bytecode generated by both versions. You will find it is exactly the same. There is therefore no reason to prefer one to the other. What you *can* get rid of is the `== True` part in each case.

Answer (score 0):

With increased number of if statements or its complexity, better use a rule Management system like JBoss Drools